# How to find disjoint subsets such that union of the sets give the motherset or main set?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, sets, subset, combinatorica

Let us define a set $\mathcal{S}=\{1,2, 3,\cdots,67\}$. I have a list of 132 subsets.

I want to obtain 16(or 17) mutually exclusive subsets such that union of such 16(or 17) is equal to $\mathcal{S}$.

In the case of 17 subsets, 2 subsets will have one element in common.

Here is the list of subsets

```
    SS={{1, 2, 32, 38}, {1, 2, 37, 38}, {1, 2, 32, 33}, {2, 3, 32, 33}, {2, 
  3, 38, 39}, {1, 2, 38, 39}, {2, 3, 33, 39}, {3, 4, 33, 34}, {2, 3, 
  33, 34}, {2, 3, 39, 40}, {3, 4, 39, 40}, {3, 4, 34, 40}, {3, 4, 40, 
  41}, {5, 6, 35, 44}, {5, 6, 43, 44}, {5, 6, 35, 36}, {6, 7, 35, 
  36}, {6, 7, 44, 45}, {5, 6, 44, 45}, {6, 7, 36, 45}, {6, 7, 45, 
  46}, {8, 9, 37, 38}, {8, 9, 38, 39}, {9, 10, 39, 47}, {9, 10, 38, 
  39}, {9, 10, 39, 40}, {10, 11, 39, 40}, {10, 11, 47, 48}, {10, 11, 
  40, 48}, {9, 10, 47, 48}, {10, 11, 48, 49}, {10, 11, 40, 41}, {11, 
  12, 48, 49}, {11, 12, 41, 49}, {11, 12, 40, 41}, {11, 12, 49, 
  50}, {11, 12, 41, 42}, {12, 13, 42, 50}, {12, 13, 49, 50}, {12, 13, 
  41, 42}, {12, 13, 42, 43}, {13, 14, 42, 43}, {13, 14, 43, 51}, {13, 
  14, 50, 51}, {12, 13, 50, 51}, {13, 14, 43, 44}, {13, 14, 51, 
  52}, {14, 15, 44, 52}, {14, 15, 51, 52}, {14, 15, 43, 44}, {14, 15, 
  52, 53}, {14, 15, 44, 45}, {15, 16, 45, 53}, {15, 16, 44, 45}, {15, 
  16, 52, 53}, {15, 16, 45, 46}, {15, 16, 53, 54}, {16, 17, 46, 
  54}, {16, 17, 53, 54}, {16, 17, 45, 46}, {18, 19, 47, 55}, {18, 19, 
  55, 56}, {18, 19, 47, 48}, {19, 20, 55, 56}, {19, 20, 47, 48}, {19, 
  20, 48, 56}, {19, 20, 56, 57}, {19, 20, 48, 49}, {20, 21, 49, 
  57}, {20, 21, 48, 49}, {20, 21, 56, 57}, {21, 22, 57, 58}, {20, 21, 
  57, 58}, {21, 22, 50, 58}, {20, 21, 49, 50}, {21, 22, 49, 50}, {21, 
  22, 58, 59}, {21, 22, 50, 51}, {22, 23, 58, 59}, {22, 23, 50, 
  51}, {22, 23, 51, 59}, {23, 24, 51, 52}, {22, 23, 51, 52}, {22, 23, 
  59, 60}, {23, 24, 52, 60}, {23, 24, 59, 60}, {24, 25, 53, 61}, {24, 
  25, 52, 53}, {23, 24, 52, 53}, {23, 24, 60, 61}, {24, 25, 60, 
  61}, {24, 25, 61, 62}, {24, 25, 53, 54}, {26, 27, 55, 56}, {26, 27, 
  56, 64}, {26, 27, 63, 64}, {26, 27, 64, 65}, {26, 27, 56, 57}, {27, 
  28, 64, 65}, {27, 28, 57, 65}, {27, 28, 56, 57}, {27, 28, 57, 
  58}, {28, 29, 57, 58}, {29, 30, 59, 66}, {28, 29, 58, 59}, {29, 30, 
  58, 59}, {29, 30, 59, 60}, {30, 31, 59, 60}, {30, 31, 60, 67}, {30, 
  31, 66, 67}, {29, 30, 66, 67}, {30, 31, 60, 61}, {1, 8, 37, 38}, {2,
   9, 38, 39}, {3, 10, 39, 40}, {4, 11, 40, 41}, {5, 14, 43, 44}, {6, 
  15, 44, 45}, {7, 16, 45, 46}, {10, 19, 47, 48}, {11, 20, 48, 
  49}, {12, 21, 49, 50}, {13, 22, 50, 51}, {14, 23, 51, 52}, {15, 24, 
  52, 53}, {16, 25, 53, 54}, {19, 26, 55, 56}, {20, 27, 56, 57}, {21, 
  28, 57, 58}, {22, 29, 58, 59}, {23, 30, 59, 60}, {24, 31, 60, 61}};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`LinearProgramming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming) for this. The vector to be optimized is a selector of which subsets to include. The constraint is that each element is included at least once. So:

```
sol = LinearProgramming[
    ConstantArray[1,132],
    Transpose @ SparseArray[SparseArray[Thread[#->1], 67]& /@ SS],
    ConstantArray[{1,1}, 67],
    ConstantArray[{0,1},132],
    Integers
]
```

> LinearProgramming::lpip: Warning: integer linear programming will use a machine-precision approximation of the inputs.
>
> {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Check:

```
Total[%103]
Union @@ Pick[SS, sol, 1]
Length @ %
```

> 18
>
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67}
>
> 67

So, it seems you need at least 18 subsets.

**Addendum**

Here is a function that encapsulates the above approach:

```
SubsetCover[subsets:{__?VectorQ}] := Module[{indexed, boole, r, c},
    indexed = ArrayComponents[subsets];
    boole = Transpose @ SparseArray[SparseArray[Thread[#->1], 67]& /@ SS];
    {r, c} = Dimensions[boole];
    Quiet[
        LinearProgramming[
            ConstantArray[1, c],
            boole,
            ConstantArray[{1, 1}, r],
            ConstantArray[{0, 1}, c],
            Integers
        ],
        LinearProgramming::lpip
    ]
]
```

Your example:

```
SubsetCover[SS]
```

> {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, I do not understand why do we have 18 subsets chosen? $4\times 18=72$, but we have only 67 elements! is it not possible to put 17 as a constraint?

Comment: @dipaknarayanan I think it's because there is no way to have 17 subsets cover all of the elements.